# Please specify the product's option(s) After update 1.6 > 1.9

Tags: product

After adding a simple product to cart it gives: Please specify the product's option(s).

How can i check which data is sended with javascript? If i debug in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Default.php
$values is empty. That is where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Low-level: look at server log for the request params.

Easier: use the developer tools built into modern browsers to view the request headers.